# Order by a collection based on two columns

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Given I have a simple collection

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200, 'cost'=>250],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100, 'cost'=>200],
]);
```

I calculate the income in vuejs by simply doing  `price - income`, in this case I will get:

> 1. -50
> 2. -100

Now I want to order by descending the results like:

> 1. -100
> 2. -50

Wonder if there is a way to order by in the collection itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in Laravel and pass the data to the view if it's an option. Use the [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) and [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortbydesc) methods:

```
$asc = $collection->sortBy(function ($i) {
    return $i['price'] - $i['cost'];
});

$desc = $collection->sortByDesc(function ($i) {
    return $i['price'] - $i['cost'];
});
```

Alternatively, you can add a new column to the collection using the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) method, so you'll be able to sort it with any JS script:

```
$collection->transform(function ($i) {
    $i['difference'] = $i['price'] - $i['cost'];
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: I tried 
       ` return $tableRows->sortByDesc(function ($row) {
            return $row['price'] - $row['cost'];
        })` but it does not work

Comment: @PrStandup just tried the code you've just shown with the data you've shown before, it works for me. You might think that `-50` is less than `-100`, but it's not. So, maybe you want to invert the logic it by replacing `sortBy` with `sortByDesc` and `sortByDesc` with `sortBy`

Comment: actually it is working but not displaying because it adds "0": {data}, "1":{data}  how do I remove keys

Comment: @PrStandup to remove keys add `->values()`

Comment: thats what I did, awesome :)